# Most efficient way to run multi-level mysqli query with php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a table:

[image]

I have a list of id's that I have selected (highlighted)

Using php and mysqli, how can I output data to the page (sorted by decending 'value', followed by the respective 'value's ascending 'name') in the most query-efficient way.

Example:

- 9

  - bbbbb
- 5

  - ddddd
- 4

  - 11111
  - hhhhh
- 3

  - ccccc
  - fffff

Comment: "are a result from a previous query" couldent you just use a join in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ($myIDArray is from a previous query):

```
$myIDArray = [2,5,6,7,9,11]; //From previous query
$sql = "SELECT value, GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name DESC SEPARATOR ',')
    FROM your_table 
    WHERE value IN (".implode(',', $myIDArray)."
    GROUP BY value
    ORDER BY value DESC";
```

After you get the result set, go through each row of the result and do something like this:

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    echo "<li>$row->value <ul><li>";
    echo implode('</li><li>', explode(",", $row->name));
    echo "</li></ul></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```